# How can I forbid access to an URL in PHP?

Tags: php

If I have a URL called: `www.example.com` and I have an application in the next URL: `www.example.com/app/`, how can I forbid access to `www.example.com` but not to the app? 
Any simple way?

Thanks.

Comment: This seems like a server configuration problem more than a PHP one.

Comment: This kind of problem is usually solved with `.htaccess`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do this from within PHP, you can simply set the correct HTTP status and exit the program:

```
if ($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] === '/') {
    header('', false, 403);
    die('Access forbidden.');
}
```

See the [header()](http://php.net/header) docs and the description of [HTTP return codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

But in the general case, @CooPer and the others are right, the server config is a better location to handle that globally.

Answer (score 2):

use .htaccess

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1

<Directory /app>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```